# How can I parse string date with regex?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have 3 possible string date.

I have to parse the date string with Regex

```
date = "13.06.2020"
date2 = "13-06-2020"
date3 = "13/06/2020"
```

```
for i in [date,date2,date3]:
    finder = re.findall(r'something',i) #I try findall but I think it doesn't work.
    print("day : " + finder[0])
    print("month : " + finder[1])
    print("year : " + finder[2])
```

It supposed to give that output for all possibilities. I figure out with **Datetime** but I can't use it. I have use **re** library

```
day:13
month:06
year:2020
```

Do you guys have any suggestions?

Comment: Please share what you have tried? Also, any specific reason why you must use regex?

Comment: is `r'something'` your RegEx pattern ?

Comment: @GiladGreen Hi man. I am just trying scrape date from a website and each website has different types. I have to parse for all possibilities.

Comment: @MuratDemir Still wondering why you must use regex. Is this for an assignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
for i in [date,date2,date3]:
    finder = re.findall(r'(\d{1,2})[\.\-\/](\d{2})[\.\-\/](\d{4})',i)
    print("day : " + finder[0][0])
    print("month : " + finder[0][1])
    print("year : " + finder[0][2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using regex to parse date strings. Use `parser.parse` from `dateutil` module (which you can install through pip using the cmd `pip install python-dateutil`)

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> for date_str in [date,date2,date3]:
...     dt = parser.parse(date_str)
...     print(f"day : {dt.day}, month: {dt.month}, year: {dt.year}")
... 
day : 13, month: 6, year: 2020
day : 13, month: 6, year: 2020
day : 13, month: 6, year: 2020
```

Comment: I have to use regex. The task's general-purpose regex, I don't know why. Thanks alot